Flutter change ButtonSegment constraints
I have a SegmentedButton with ButtonSegments. I normally only have 2 segments and everything goes fine:

However, there is a setting where a third option comes, and then the text overflows:

How can i change the padding of the ButtonSegments so that there is less space around the Label/icon
My code:
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  child: SegmentedButton(
    segments: [
      ButtonSegment(
        value: 'local',
        label: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.locally,
        ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.smartphone),
      ),
      if (isAdvancedOptions)
        ButtonSegment(
          value: 'selfHost',
          label: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context)!
                .selfHost,
          ),
          icon: Icon(Symbols.database),
        ),
      ButtonSegment(
        value: 'online',
        label: Text(
          AppLocalizations.of(context)!.online,
        ),
        icon: Icon(Icons.language),
      ),
    ],
    selected: {selectedStorage},
    onSelectionChanged: (selected) {
      setState(() {
        selectedStorage = selected.first;
      });
      logger.i(selected.toString());
    },
    style: isAdvancedOptions
        ? ButtonStyle(
            tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize
                .shrinkWrap,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity(
                horizontal: -3, vertical: -3),
          )
        : null,
  ),
),

I've tried wrapping them in flexible, expanded but nothing worked. How do i change the actual space around the items inside the ButtonSegment

Try to add padding inside your "ButtonStyle" like this: "padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5))"

Use padding property in style, something like this:
SegmentedButton(
...
  style: SegmentedButton.styleFrom(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
  ),
...
);

